# How can I disable a button while NSXMLParser runs, then enable it when it completes?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have a `viewController` which imports `XMLParser.h` as the class `xmlParser`

I'm passing an `NSURL` object in my `viewController` to the `xmlParser` class with the `getXML` method below

`goButton` is the button I tap to call the `getXML` method below.  I disable the button which I tapped to trigger the `getXML` method, but I'm not sure where to put the code to enable it again once the xmlParser has finished parsing the returned XML.

```
- (IBAction) getXML {
    goButton.enabled = NO;

    // allocate and initialize the xmlParser 
    xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] init];

// then generate the URL we are going to pass to it and call the fetchXML method passing the URL.
    NSURL *xmlurl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/myfile.xml"];
    [xmlParser fetchXMLFromURL:xmlurl];

    // release objects
    [xmlurl release];
    [xmlParser release];

}
```

---

As per @Squeegy recommendation, I modified my code.

```
- (IBAction) getXML {
    goButton.enabled = NO;

    xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] init];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(parseInBackground:) withObject:xmlParser];

}

- (void)parseInBackground:(XMLParser*)parser {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSURL *xmlurl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/myfile.xml"];

    [parser fetchXMLFromURL:xmlurl];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didFinishXMLParsing:) withObject:parser];

    [xmlurl release];
    [pool drain];

}

- (void)didFinishXMLParsing:(NSXMLParser*)parser {
    goButton.enabled = YES;
}
```

Looks to be working until it gets to the line

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didFinishXMLParsing:) withObject:parser];
```

The compiler complains as follows:

```
2010-02-17 00:22:20.574 XMLApp[2443:521b] *** -[viewController performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1285a0
2010-02-17 00:22:20.578 XMLApp[2443:521b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[viewController performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1285a0'
2010-02-17 00:22:20.583 XMLApp[2443:521b] Stack: (
    861696817,
    860329709,
    861700631,
    861203093,
    861166272,
    18715,
    846004025,
    845672609,
    848189713
)
```

Comment: My bad, that method is `- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait`.  I gave the wrong method name in my answer.

Comment: @Squeegy OK, that helped somewhat.  No errors now, but my function fetchXMLFromURL isn't actually doing what it's supposed to.  It's as if control is returning to the main thread before the parser actually initiates the connection to the server for the xml file.  It was working perfectly before the threading was introduced

Comment: Maybe you should try a simpler example in a sandbox with threading.  It can be tough to get your head around.  Sounds liek this may be a separate issue for a separate question.  THis one is getting sort of crowded.

Comment: @Squeegy OK I guess this question has got pretty ugly.  Thanks for the help, I thought there'd be an easier way to disable and re-enable a button than threading.  Seems unnecessarily complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)getXML {
    goButton.enabled = NO;

    xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] init];
    NSURL *xmlurl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/myfile.xml"];
    [xmlParser fetchXMLFromURL:xmlurl];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(parseInBackground) withObject:xmlParser];

    [xmlurl release];
    [xmlParser release];
}

- (void)parseInBackground:(NSXMLParser*)parser {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    [parser parse];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didFinishXMLParsing:)
                           withObject:parser
                        waitUntilDone:NO];

    [pool drain];
}

- (void)didFinishXMLParsing:(NSXMLParser*)parser {
    goButton.enabled = YES;
}
```

The trick is to do the processing on a background thread, which allows the UI to do stuff.  When parsing is done, you have to make any UI changes back on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks @Squeegy but I think you misunderstood my question but I can't be sure as I don't quite understand your code.  My parsing code is in an external class whose sole purpose is to be a generic class I can import for parsing in my apps.  I have imported my parser class' header file in my view controller and I call the parser from within my viewController.

Comment: @Squeegy my objective is just to disable the button so the method can't be called multiple times before it's even finished the previous request.  So I just want the user to be prevented from pressing the button until the parsing has completed.

Comment: This does that.  `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` allows you to run a method in a background thread.  This is important to allow your UI on the main thread to update (disabling the button).  Your app is responsive, but your button is disabled.  When parsing is done, it says "Hey main thread, i'm done with parsing", and the main thread enables the button.  This is important because *only* the main thread can update the UI.  So your parser class would execute it's own parsing methods in a background thread,  and then call a method of it's delegate on the main thread when it's done.

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying I think.  I'm getting a runtime error, see below:  
2010-02-16 23:54:31.935 XMLApp[2371:640f] *** -[XMLParser parse]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x152340


The object being passed to parseInBackground is a type XMLParser which is my custom class.  It's not an NSXMLParser

Comment: `NSXMLParser` has a method called `parse`.  You need to call the method that does the parsing in your custom class.  `fetchXMLFromURL:` I suppose it would be.

Comment: Fixed my answer to call the right method, my bad.  But when in doubt about these things, look up methods in the docs.  That would have cleared this one up pretty easily.

Comment: Also, I just made up these methods, but you can use whatever you want.  You dont need to pass the xmlParser object around if you don't need it.  In that case the selectors you call have no argument, and the `withObject:` argument becomes simply `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

When the parser finishes parsing, it will call it's delegate's:

`- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser`

In that method, you can re-enable the button. You should probably do so with a `performSelectorInMainThread` call, since it involves changing a view.

Comment: @pgb can you elaborate on how this would be implemented?  I'm not changing view, `viewController` is my view which calls the parser.  The parser is not in another view, it's just in an external class which is an `NSObject`